# Parse dynamic parameters from url in action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, model-binding, specifications

In test project I try to learn specification pattern and how use it in online store. Products specifications grouped by category e.g.:  Color(blue, withe, etc), Height(100cm, 200cm, etc). Specifications added to product based on selected category in product. In all articles that I have read, specifications in the action are known as parameters. But if specifications added dynamically in my test project, I don't know how purse it. For instance, I have this controller action:

```
    public ActionResult Products(string category, 
        string[] specificationNameValuePairs, int page = 1, int pageSize = 9, 
        string order = "Position, Name", string ordertype = "asc")
    {
    ...
    }
```

How can I bind specificationNameValuePairs in this action? Or I must redesign my project and use static specifications and for each specifications category create model for binding?

Answer (score 0):

You must need to know about Url.Action method. Please check the below link, it may help.

[Url Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759189/how-does-url-action-work-asp-net-mvc)