# Why changing image link invokes controller asynchronously in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm changing the link of an image on the client side and it invokes the controller asynchronously.

I don't understand this behavior, could someone explain me what is happening?

Why url adding actually invokes the controller by default, moreover it happens asynchronously.

```
    <script>
        $("#refreshLnk").click(function () {
            $("#cap").attr('src', '@Url.Action("CaptchaImage")?' + new Date().getTime());
        });
    </script>

   <img id="cap" alt="Captcha" src="@Url.Action("CaptchaImage")" style="" />
   <a id="refreshLnk" href="#">refresh</a>

   public ActionResult CaptchaImage()
   {
   }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve, because your code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I think everything is pretty much explains itself, I'm not trying to achieve anything I just asked nicely if someone could explain me why changing URL attribute automatically invokes server side control.

Comment: I didn't meant to offend you or anything. But, what you are doing does not seem to be a good solution. You got your answer as to why the controller is being invoked, but you shouldn't be changing the image source like this.

Comment: Why shouldn't I change the image source like this? What so bad in that approach? For me this solution is perfect and answers my needs.

Comment: Because, you simply you don't have to use jQuery to add the current time to the link. You should create a partial view, and update it using ajax.

Comment: I assume that the image changes, every time you click on refresh. So, where do those images come from?

Comment: oh No, you just don't know the reason for doing that, I'm not passing the current time for "just knowing the time", I pass it to get rid of cache in IE, Why people try to answer the questions that's are not were asked, that's annoying, if you wanna help just answer the question and don't say "it does not make sense why you are doing this"
otherwise just don't answer. Nothing personal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal and expected behavior. When you click the button, your script changes the src attribute of the image to something like "/CaptchaImage?1376967614675". Browser tries to render the image, thus invokes this url. This triggers the  CaptchaImage method in the controller.

There are many posts related to your question, you can start with this one: [How does Url.Action work Asp.net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759189/690329). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's make sense to me.